# Kendo React Grid - Add a hyperlink column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-ui, grid

I'm using the Kendo React Grid and trying to find a way to add a column to my grid which is a Hyperlink.  This was straight forward with the Kendo React wrappers or jQuery widgets but I can't seem to find a way with pure React components.

I have tried creating a React Component similar to:

```html
class LinkCell extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);  
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <td><a href={this.props.url}> { this.props.title }</a>
   </td>
  );
 }
}
```

This works fine if I want the same for the href and title in every row.  What I can't seem to do is find a way to pass in a column from the current rows data  (in Kendo jQuery you would use #: COLUN #

Answer (score 0):

In your example the `{ this.props.dataItem}` will be value for the current row based on the `data` passed to the Grid.
Note that you can even use it as functional component. In that case you need to skip the `this` keyword of the props.

```
  <Column 
   field="ProductID" 
   title="ID" 
   width="40px" 
   cell={ (props) => 
      <td>
         <a href={props.dataItem.ProductID}>
            { props.dataItem.ProductName}
         </a>
       </td>
       }
    />
```

All available props of the cell, that the grid will pass is available in the official [api reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/api/GridCellProps/) of the Kendo React Grid